# Generalize a result to any category.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Consider two categories $\mathscr{C}$ and $\mathscr{D}$ where $\mathscr{C}= Grp$ and $\mathscr{D}= \textbf{Set}$, then we are taking the forgetful and faithful  functor $p$ (this is, we have a group with a operation, so applying the functor only give us the set, we forget the operation), therefore we want to relate the notion of a free object (the left adjoint of the forgetful functor evaluated in some fix object of the category $\mathscr{D}$) $F(X)$ attached to $X \in ob(\mathscr{D})$ and we want to show that this provides a natural transformation:

$$\tau_{X,Y}: Mor_{\mathscr{C}}(F(X),Y) \to Mor_{\mathscr{D}}(X, p(Y))$$
$$(F(X) \to^{\varphi} Y) \mapsto \varphi |_{X}$$

this map $\tau_{X,Y}$ is a bijection because the universally repelling object property gives the inverse map.

The thing is What is the generalization of this result to arbitrary categories $\mathscr{C}$ and $\mathscr{D}$ ? (I think everything should be same only changing the restriction of $\varphi$ but I don't know how to do that)

Thanks a lot :) for your help.

This is:

Theorem: The map $\tau_{X,Y}: Mor_{\mathscr{C}}(F(X),Y) \to Mor_{\mathscr{D}}(X, p(Y))$ defined as $(F(X) \to^{\varphi} Y) \mapsto ?$ is a natural transformation for any two categories given.

So I want to know what goes in the place of $\varphi |_{X}$ or what to change in the above information to prove that theorem :)

Comment: It's unclear which result you are trying to generalise. All I see is general mumbo jumbo about left-right adjoints. Can you state the result you are looking at explicitly?

Comment: Well the result I want to generalize is that the function $\tau$ is in fact a natural transformation (bijection in fact)

Comment: that is hardly any more explicit. Please state the result as a theorem. State what is given, and what is the claim. Then we can proceed.

Comment: ok, let me edit the post :).

Comment: ready, there is it :)

Comment: do you mean to say: "given an adjunction, the function \tau_{X,Y} is a bijection"? if all you have are the two categories, then there is no function $\tau$. If you mean to start with an adjunction, then the function \tau is, by definition of adjunction, a bijection, natural in each argument.

Comment: Ok, but what I think we are trying to do is to construct a natural transformation from the left adjoint functor to the forgetful functor, but before that we need this stuff, so I want to know first if $\tau$ defined as above a bijection no matter the categories

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: Well I don't know how to explain this better, I only was trying to write the same as in my post only defining what does it means to restrict a morphism in an arbitrary category

Comment: In fact can you explain the las part of your above comment (the above of the last you made ) please?

Answer (score 2):

I guess (from the comment discussion mostly) your question is not really about free objects but rather: given an adjunction $F \dashv U$, how can I explicitly write the bijection $\hom(FA, B) \to \hom(A, UB)$ so that the special case $\mathsf{Set} \leftrightarrows \mathsf{Grp}$ gives me the restriction $\varphi \mapsto \varphi\restriction A$?

---

Given $F \colon \mathscr C \to \mathscr D$ left adjoint to $U \colon \mathscr D \to \mathscr C$, one get two natural transformations
$$ \eta \colon \mathrm{id}_{\mathcal C} \to UF,\quad 
\varepsilon \colon FU \to \mathrm{id}_{\mathcal C}, $$
named *unit* and *counit*, defined componentwise as follow:
$$ \begin{aligned}
\hom(FA,FA) &\stackrel \sim \to \hom(A,UFA)\\
\mathrm{id}_A &\mapsto \eta_A
\end{aligned} 
\qquad \qquad
\begin{aligned}
\hom(FUB,B) &\stackrel \sim \to \hom(UB,UB)\\
\varepsilon_B &\leftarrow \mathrm{id}_B
\end{aligned}$$

The naturality of the bijection between hom-sets given by the adjunction allows us to rewrite it as:
$$ \begin{aligned}
\hom(FA,B) &\to \hom(A,UB) \\
(FA \stackrel \varphi B) &\mapsto (A \stackrel {\eta_A} \to UFA \stackrel {U\varphi} \to UB)
\end{aligned}$$

---

In your example $F \colon \mathsf{Set} \leftrightarrows \mathsf{Grp} :\!p$, the unit $\eta$ is componentwise the inclusion of $A$ into the (underlying set of the) free group over $A$, so precomposing by $\eta_A$ acts as the restriction.

Comment: Sorry, but in U it should be C to D isn't?, thanks for the help :)